# Parsing html for specific script type

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, vine

In the html code, Vine has `<script type="application/ld+json">` with links to all the videos on the page, how would I got about accessing this JSON?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://vine.co/tags/funny'
source_code = requests.get(url)
plain_text = source_code.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a css selector:

```
soup.select("script[type=application/ld+json]")
```

Or find_all setting `type="application/ld+json"`:

```
soup.find_all("script",type="application/ld+json")
```

Both gives you:

```
[<script type="application/ld+json">\n          {\n            "@context": "http://schema.org",\n            "@type": "ItemList",\n            "url": "https://vine.co/tags/funny",\n            "itemListElement": [\n              \n              {\n                "@type": "ListItem",\n                "position": 1,\n                "url": "https://vine.co/v/iLKgAXeqwqu"\n              },\n              \n              {\n                "@type": "ListItem",\n                "position": 2,\n                "url": "https://vine.co/v/iLK6p2UHDTl"\n              },\n              \n              {\n                "@type": "ListItem",\n                "position": 3,\n                "url": "https://vine.co/v/iLKrbIeXPTH"\n              },\n              \n              {\n                "@type": "ListItem",\n                "position": 4,\n                "url": "https://vine.co/v/iLKrbZ5zir0"\n              },\n              \n              {\n                "@type": "ListItem",\n                "position": 5,\n                "url": "https://vine.co/v/iLKvxUwLUxr"\n              },\n              \n              {\n                "@type": "ListItem",\n                "position": 6,\n                "url": "https://vine.co/v/iLKvnVOd7VA"\n              },\n              \n              {\n                "@type": "ListItem",\n                "position": 7,\n                "url": "https://vine.co/v/iLKv73UQmjB"\n              },\n              \n              {\n                "@type": "ListItem",\n                "position": 8,\n                "url": "https://vine.co/v/iLKvBeO9Fmt"\n              },\n              \n              {\n                "@type": "ListItem",\n                "position": 9,\n                "url": "https://vine.co/v/iLKnrqMDYeD"\n              },\n              \n              {\n                "@type": "ListItem",\n                "position": 10,\n                "url": "https://vine.co/v/iLKnWrjMqwE"\n              },\n              \n              {\n                "@type": "ListItem",\n                "position": 11,\n                "url": "https://vine.co/v/iLK17Bg1wt0"\n              },\n              \n              {\n                "@type": "ListItem",\n                "position": 12,\n                "url": "https://vine.co/v/iLK5ExAZ7WB"\n              },\n              \n              {\n                "@type": "ListItem",\n                "position": 13,\n                "url": "https://vine.co/v/iLK5Eg7vHM7"\n              },\n              \n              {\n                "@type": "ListItem",\n                "position": 14,\n                "url": "https://vine.co/v/iLKitbix3pb"\n              },\n              \n              {\n                "@type": "ListItem",\n                "position": 15,\n                "url": "https://vine.co/v/iLKOleYJhUp"\n              },\n              \n              {\n                "@type": "ListItem",\n                "position": 16,\n                "url": "https://vine.co/v/iLKOTFgXVFQ"\n              },\n              \n              {\n                "@type": "ListItem",\n                "position": 17,\n                "url": "https://vine.co/v/iLKMI6t91xe"\n              },\n              \n              {\n                "@type": "ListItem",\n                "position": 18,\n                "url": "https://vine.co/v/iLKMX6p0TD6"\n              },\n              \n              {\n                "@type": "ListItem",\n                "position": 19,\n                "url": "https://vine.co/v/iLKM6Hh1nzr"\n              },\n              \n              {\n                "@type": "ListItem",\n                "position": 20,\n                "url": "https://vine.co/v/iLKhQWVIAj3"\n              }\n              \n            ]\n          }\n        </script>]
```

To get it into *json*, all you need is to *json.loads* the text, also since there is only one, you can use *select_one* or *find*:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
url = 'https://vine.co/tags/funny'
source_code = requests.get(url)
plain_text = source_code.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')
# js = json.loads(soup.find("script",type="application/ld+json").text)
js = json.loads(soup.select_one("script[type=application/ld+json]").text)
print(js)
```

Which gives you:

```
{u'url': u'https://vine.co/tags/funny', u'@context': u'http://schema.org', u'itemListElement': [{u'url': u'https://vine.co/v/iLKgAXeqwqu', u'position': 1, u'@type': u'ListItem'}, {u'url': u'https://vine.co/v/iLK6p2UHDTl', u'position': 2, u'@type': u'ListItem'}, {u'url': u'https://vine.co/v/iLKrbIeXPTH', u'position': 3, u'@type': u'ListItem'}, {u'url': u'https://vine.co/v/iLKrbZ5zir0', u'position': 4, u'@type': u'ListItem'}, {u'url': u'https://vine.co/v/iLKvxUwLUxr', u'position': 5, u'@type': u'ListItem'}, {u'url': u'https://vine.co/v/iLKvnVOd7VA', u'position': 6, u'@type': u'ListItem'}, {u'url': u'https://vine.co/v/iLKv73UQmjB', u'position': 7, u'@type': u'ListItem'}, {u'url': u'https://vine.co/v/iLKvBeO9Fmt', u'position': 8, u'@type': u'ListItem'}, {u'url': u'https://vine.co/v/iLKnrqMDYeD', u'position': 9, u'@type': u'ListItem'}, {u'url': u'https://vine.co/v/iLKnWrjMqwE', u'position': 10, u'@type': u'ListItem'}, {u'url': u'https://vine.co/v/iLK17Bg1wt0', u'position': 11, u'@type': u'ListItem'}, {u'url': u'https://vine.co/v/iLK5ExAZ7WB', u'position': 12, u'@type': u'ListItem'}, {u'url': u'https://vine.co/v/iLK5Eg7vHM7', u'position': 13, u'@type': u'ListItem'}, {u'url': u'https://vine.co/v/iLKitbix3pb', u'position': 14, u'@type': u'ListItem'}, {u'url': u'https://vine.co/v/iLKOleYJhUp', u'position': 15, u'@type': u'ListItem'}, {u'url': u'https://vine.co/v/iLKOTFgXVFQ', u'position': 16, u'@type': u'ListItem'}, {u'url': u'https://vine.co/v/iLKMI6t91xe', u'position': 17, u'@type': u'ListItem'}, {u'url': u'https://vine.co/v/iLKMX6p0TD6', u'position': 18, u'@type': u'ListItem'}, {u'url': u'https://vine.co/v/iLKM6Hh1nzr', u'position': 19, u'@type': u'ListItem'}, {u'url': u'https://vine.co/v/iLKhQWVIAj3', u'position': 20, u'@type': u'ListItem'}], u'@type': u'ItemList'}
```

The last step is just to parse  js to get the urls, they are in a list of dicts you can access with `js["itemListElement"]` :

```
In [18]: js = json.loads(soup.select_one("script[type=application/ld+json]").text)

In [19]: all_urls = [dct["url"] for dct in js["itemListElement"]]

In [20]: print(all_urls)
['https://vine.co/v/iLK2rbzBU50', 'https://vine.co/v/iLK2iw305nH', 'https://vine.co/v/iLK2AadMMTO', 'https://vine.co/v/iLK2WY1EMWJ', 'https://vine.co/v/iLKQ6AdTtXE', 'https://vine.co/v/iLKQAPtKdwF', 'https://vine.co/v/iLKQAKpVJAM', 'https://vine.co/v/iLKxQqIH65I', 'https://vine.co/v/iLKxAuJwe2v', 'https://vine.co/v/iLKPQhZprq3', 'https://vine.co/v/iLKPIij7EzW', 'https://vine.co/v/iLKU697X3iQ', 'https://vine.co/v/iLKFZDTUHla', 'https://vine.co/v/iLKtPzahtel', 'https://vine.co/v/iLKTbpb1hgO', 'https://vine.co/v/iLKTaKYEx06', 'https://vine.co/v/iLKInbjuAnY', 'https://vine.co/v/iLKIBDbbDHY', 'https://vine.co/v/iLKjPxPz7bK', 'https://vine.co/v/iLKjFzKJwYF']
```

Comment: what if find_all gives me multiple scripts and then i want to filter out based on some json tag?

Comment: When I do soup.select_one(...) and print it I have the expected script with type json, but when I say, .text, I receive I blank string back and it says "expecting value".