# How to extract json <script> elements with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to extract different elements from a JSON part of the page, each element under `@type`.

I tried [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54319920/extracting-json-from-html-using-beautifulsoup-python.) but could not figure it out.

```
data = soup.findAll('script', {'type':'application/ld+json'})
oJson = json.loads(data.text)["model"] gives an error of 
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'
```

Would appreciate help.

```
<script type="application/ld+json"
{"@context":"https://schema.org/",
"@type":"Product","brand":"Salomon","category":"Basecaps","description":"<p>Leichte Sportkappe f&uuml;r Sport bei Sonne und Regen</p>","image":"https://static.bergzeit.com/product_gallery_regular/1118101-006_pic1.jpg",

"model":[
{"@type":"ProductModel","color":"fiery red","image":"https://static.bergzeit.com/product_gallery_regular/1118101-003_pic1.jpg","name":"Cross Cap","offers":[{"@type":"Offer","availability":"http://schema.org/OutOfStock","name":"fiery red Cross Cap","price":24.95,"priceCurrency":"EUR"}],"size":"ONE SIZE","sku":"1118101-003","url":"https://www.bergzeit.de/p/salomon-cross-cap/1118101/#itemId=1118101-003"},

{"@type":"ProductModel","color":"nightshade","image":"https://static.bergzeit.com/product_gallery_regular/1118101-005_pic1.jpg","name":"Cross Cap","offers":[{"@type":"Offer","availability":"http://schema.org/InStock","name":"nightshade Cross Cap","price":24.77,"priceCurrency":"EUR"}],"size":"ONE SIZE","sku":"1118101-005","url":"https://www.bergzeit.de/p/salomon-cross-cap/1118101/#itemId=1118101-005"},

{"@type":"ProductModel","color":"deep black","image":"https://static.bergzeit.com/product_gallery_regular/1118101-001_pic1.jpg","name":"Cross Cap","offers":[{"@type":"Offer","availability":"http://schema.org/InStock","name":"deep black Cross Cap","price":24.95,"priceCurrency":"EUR"}],"size":"ONE SIZE","sku":"1118101-001","url":"https://www.bergzeit.de/p/salomon-cross-cap/1118101/#itemId=1118101-001"},

{"@type":"ProductModel","color":"chambray blue","image":"https://static.bergzeit.com/product_gallery_regular/1118101-002_pic1.jpg","name":"Cross Cap","offers":[{"@type":"Offer","availability":"http://schema.org/OutOfStock","name":"chambray blue Cross Cap","price":24.95,"priceCurrency":"EUR"}],"size":"ONE SIZE","sku":"1118101-002","url":"https://www.bergzeit.de/p/salomon-cross-cap/1118101/#itemId=1118101-002"},

{"@type":"ProductModel","color":"bering sea","image":"https://static.bergzeit.com/product_gallery_regular/1118101-008_pic1.jpg","name":"Cross Cap","offers":[{"@type":"Offer","availability":"http://schema.org/OutOfStock","name":"bering sea Cross Cap","price":24.95,"priceCurrency":"EUR"}],"size":"ONE SIZE","sku":"1118101-008","url":"https://www.bergzeit.de/p/salomon-cross-cap/1118101/#itemId=1118101-008"},

{"@type":"ProductModel","color":"deep lichen green","image":"https://static.bergzeit.com/product_gallery_regular/1118101-007_pic1.jpg","name":"Cross Cap","offers":[{"@type":"Offer","availability":"http://schema.org/OutOfStock","name":"deep lichen green Cross Cap","price":24.95,"priceCurrency":"EUR"}],"size":"ONE SIZE","sku":"1118101-007","url":"https://www.bergzeit.de/p/salomon-cross-cap/1118101/#itemId=1118101-007"},

{"@type":"ProductModel","color":"white","image":"https://static.bergzeit.com/product_gallery_regular/1118101-004_pic1.jpg","name":"Cross Cap","offers":[{"@type":"Offer","availability":"http://schema.org/InStock","name":"white Cross Cap","price":24.95,"priceCurrency":"EUR"}],"size":"ONE SIZE","sku":"1118101-004","url":"https://www.bergzeit.de/p/salomon-cross-cap/1118101/#itemId=1118101-004"},

{"@type":"ProductModel","color":"peach amber","image":"https://static.bergzeit.com/product_gallery_regular/1118101-006_pic1.jpg","name":"Cross Cap","offers":[{"@type":"Offer","availability":"http://schema.org/InStock","name":"peach amber Cross Cap","price":24.63,"priceCurrency":"EUR"}],"size":"ONE SIZE","sku":"1118101-006","url":"https://www.bergzeit.de/p/salomon-cross-cap/1118101/#itemId=1118101-006"}],"name":"Cross Cap","offers":[{"@type":"AggregateOffer","availability":"http://schema.org/InStock","highPrice":24.95,"lowPrice":24.63,"priceCurrency":"EUR"}],"productId":"1118101","url":"https://www.bergzeit.de/p/salomon-cross-cap/1118101/"}
</script>
```

Comment: data = soup.findAll('script', {'type':'application/ld+json'}), edited in the post.

Comment: soup.findAll returns a (possibly empty) list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using deprecated syntax: `findAll` should be `find_all`.

Next, `find_all` returns a list, which has no such attribute as `text`.

Here is a working example of extracting that data:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import json

headers= {
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

r = requests.get("https://www.bergzeit.co.uk/p/black-diamond-womens-focus-climbing-shoe/3005027/#itemId=3005027-001", headers=headers)

soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
script_w_data = soup.select_one('div[class^="product-detailed-page"] script[type="application/ld+json"]').string
json_obj = json.loads(script_w_data)
print(json_obj['brand'],'|',  json_obj['description'])
```

Result in terminal:

```
Black Diamond | Performance statement from the first Black Diamond climbing shoe series - world premiere
```

See Requests documentation [here](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html), and also [BeautifulSoup documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Comment: Thanks! in the same code I want to extract the "longDescription" that is under the <script> tag however i'm not sure how to reference it (https://www.bergzeit.de/p/salewa-toxo-30-kletterhelm/5048225/#itemId=5048225-001). Can you help?

Comment: You're welcome @Vaidas I cannot find `longDescription` in that particular script tag. There is another script tag containing it. You need to access the script content - like I did in my code, then split the actual json-like data from it, then load it as a json object, and then you can access its keys.

Comment: Sorry, but still having issue with it, because i cannot correctly reference the right script tag. I used `script_w_data = soup.find_all('script')[9].string` but that led to `*** json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)`

Comment: I suggest locating the (other?) script tag you need using a content locator. This means looking at that script's content, identifying a unique, constant value to that string, and locating the string based on that. The following example, using `re`, should help you figure it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31958637/beautifulsoup-search-by-text-inside-a-tag @Vaidas

Answer (score 0):

Assume the text in the question is assigned to a variable named *data* then...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import json

soup = BS(data, 'lxml')

for script in soup.find_all('script'):
    j = ''.join(script.getText().splitlines()[1:])
    for model in json.loads(j)['model']:
        print(model['sku']) # for example
```

**Output:**

```
1118101-003
1118101-005
1118101-001
1118101-002
1118101-008
1118101-007
1118101-004
1118101-006
```